# Joomla 3.2 onAfterInitialise() Session

Tags: plugins, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I have created System plugin with event onAfterInitialise() and I get URL string and set session in it if URL is what I'm waiting for. After that I redirect to root page and grab session. And it works ok. But if I have another URL I rewrite session in onAfterInitialise() method, but it gives me old session, so I need to refresh to get a new one.

Can I do automatic rewrite of session? Here is the code:

```
function onAfterInitialise()
{
    $session = &JFactory::getSession();
    $jApp = &JFactory::getApplication();

    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $url = str_replace('/','',$url);

    if($url != "" && $url != NULL )
    {
        if($url == "something"){
            $session->clear('newRequest');
            $jApp->redirect('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
        } else {
            $db =  &JFactory::getDBO();
            $query = ' SELECT *'
                    .' FROM #__new_requests '
                    .' WHERE url ="'.$url.'" AND state = 1';
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $newRequest= $db->loadObjectList();
            if($newRequest!= NULL)
            {
                $session->clear('newRequest');
                $newRequestArray = array();
                $newRequestArray['color'] = $marque[0]->color;
                $newRequestArray['image'] = $marque[0]->image;
                $newRequestArray['banner'] = $marque[0]->banner;

                $session->set( 'newRequest', $newRequestArray);
                $jApp->redirect('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was template caching. I set up `devmode="1"` in params.ini of template.